# How to kill a completion handler after a specific timestamp

Tags: swift, background-process, completionhandler

I have written completion handler in a button action just like below code.

```
func backgroundTask(arg: Bool, completion: (Bool) -> ()) {

    completion(arg)
}
```

In my button click

```
backgroundTask(arg: true, completion: { (success) -> Void in
    if success { 
          print("true")
    } else {
         print("false")
    }
})
```

When the user presses button for several times the completion handler is returning that much of time.

*Returning of completion handler many times is needed.*

I need to put a time stamp, after that the completion handler need not to return.

Comment: We need to know how you perform the background task.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly you could kill a completion handler by making it optional `... completion: ((Bool) -> ())? )` and when it's appropriate set it to `nil`. But I'm not sure about your specific case and how would it fit into your app.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply cancel a closure. What you can do instead is create a `DispatchWorkItem` containing the function call and you can cancel the work item. Instead of simply calling `backgroundTask`, you should create the `DispatchWorkItem` every time the user presses the button, call `perform` on the item and call cancel if the deadline has passed.

Self contained playground example:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func backgroundTask(arg: Bool, completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
    completion(arg)
}

backgroundTask(arg: true, completion: { (success) -> Void in
    if success {
        print("true")
    } else {
        print("false")
    }
})

let workItem = DispatchWorkItem(block: { backgroundTask(arg: true, completion: {
    (success) -> Void in
    if success {
        print("true")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2, execute: {
            print("Delayed success") //As long as the deadline is smaller than the deadline of `workItem.cancel()`, this will be printed
        })
    } else {
        print("false")
    }
})})

workItem.perform()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3, execute: {
    workItem.cancel()
    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works if I understood you correctly:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let completionCancelDeadline: TimeInterval = 2.5

class Worker {
    init() {}

    private var completion: ((Bool) -> ())?

    func backgroundTask(arg: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> ())?) {
        self.completion = completion

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + completionCancelDeadline) {
            self.completion = nil
        }

        worker(arg: arg)
    }

    private func worker(arg: Bool) {
        let randomTaskDuration = TimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(5))

        // randomTaskDuration is to simulate how long it's going to take the background task to complete
        // and if it completes later than the completionCancelDeadline then the completion will be nil
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + randomTaskDuration) {
            print("Time the background task took: \(randomTaskDuration) second(s)")
            print("Should the completion exist: \(randomTaskDuration < completionCancelDeadline)")
            self.completion?(arg)
            print("") // Adding a new line intentionally to separate each call
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func buttonTap() {
        let worker = Worker()
        worker.backgroundTask(arg: true) { success in
            print("Completion called")
        }
    }
}

let vc = ViewController()
vc.buttonTap()
vc.buttonTap()
vc.buttonTap()
vc.buttonTap()
```